# Move sematics in functions could have a lot of options | Is there a cleaner way? C++

Tags: c++, move

##### Move sematics in functions could have a lot of options | Is there a cleaner way? C++

Say we have a function `append` with `key` and `value` as parameters. Then I currently would have to define 4 functions to enable move sematics. So for two parameters this is still doable. Though sometimes a function that requires move sematics has a lot more parameters, therefore too much different functions to keep the code maintainable.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve move sematics, perhaps using some form of templates? Or with variadic templates?

Example function `append` with 2 parameters.

```cpp
constexpr
auto&       append(
    const Key&      key,
    const Value&    value
) {
    ...
}
constexpr
auto&       append(
    Key&&           key,
    const Value&    value
) {
    ...
}
constexpr
auto&       append(
    const Key&      key,
    Value&&         value
) {
    ...
}
constexpr
auto&       append(
    Key&&           key,
    Value&&         value
) {
    ...
}
```

This would get a little out of hand for a function with 6 parameters that all require move sematics.

Any solutions?

Comment: Yes, look up forwarding references. Also check out how `try_emplace()` and `insert_or_assign` are implemented in the standard containers.

Comment: To be frank, I moved away from move semantics years ago and could not be happier. Move semantics is optional. There are other simpler options out there.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Thanks I have looked it up, though I am not using classes `map` or `vector`. This example is about my custom `dictionary` class. Could you perhaps create a mini example how I could implement a forwarding reference to my append function as a demonstration?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher - I understand, currently for the functions that have a lot of parameters I do the same, though when a class uses internal pointers (like some of my classes) I hate to ignore move sematics because of a lot of parameters.

Comment: I know you're making your own, but you can copy the design. One moment, I'll make an answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Great thanks! I indeed doubted if that was what you meant. Though `try_emplace` seems to apply the same architect as `append`. Patiently waiting though! :)

Comment: @user39847589375345 Have you considered intrusive pointers? All the major libraries that deal with large objects (Eigen,OpenCV,Armadillo,etc) use some sort of intrusive pointer implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are *forwarding references* that can accept both lvalues and rvalues. Something like this:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

template <typename K, typename V>
struct A
{
    template <std::convertible_to<K> A, std::convertible_to<V> B>
    void append(A &&a, B &&b)
    {
        K key = std::forward<A>(a);
        V value = std::forward<B>(b);
    }
};
```

`std::forward` then acts as a conditional move, moving the argument only if an rvalue was received.

---

But rather than accepting exactly two arguments, I would mimic `try_emplace()` and `insert_or_assign()` from standard containers:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

template <typename K, typename V>
struct A
{
    template <typename A = K, typename ...B>
    requires std::constructible_from<K, A> && std::constructible_from<V, B...>
    void append(K &&a, B &&... b)
    {
        K key(std::forward<A>(a));
        V value(std::forward<B>(b)...);
    }
};
```

Now, they use two overloads (for the first parameter being `const T &` and `T &&`), but that seems pointless, except for allowing braced lists to be passed to the first argument, which can also be achieved by adding `= K` as the default template argument.

---

I would bother with the above only if the function needs to be optimal, e.g. if you're writing your own container.

In less demanding places, I'd do as @user17732522 suggests and pass by value, then `std::move()`. This incurs one extra move compared to a reference (either a forwarding one, or 2<sup>N</sup> overloads as in the question), which should be good enough.

Comment: Great, super detailed explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply take the arguments by-value and then `std::move` them into the container's storage. This may incur one extra move construction if a glvalue of the same type is passed as argument, but will otherwise cost the same in terms of constructor calls as overloading on both lvalues and rvalues would. The move construction should normally be cheap and can often be optimized away entirely.

```
constexpr
auto&       append(
    Key      key,
    Value    value
) {
    // when constructing the container element use `std::move(key) and `std::move(value)`
}
```

Comment: This would either create a copy for the parameter or it would move the object when the client-side could still need the object. Correct me if I misunderstand your suggestion.

Comment: @user39847589375345 Nothing changes for the client. The client chooses to pass an lvalue or `std::move` it. In either case the function parameter is constructed correspondingly by copy or move construction. Then you move construct the container element from the parameter. So you only have a copy if a lvalue is passed directly, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: @user39847589375345 If you are using C++20 the suggestion by HolyBlackCat works nicely as well to actually avoid the extra move operation, but it is a bit cumbersome to implement it without C++20 concepts.